# unable to discover and connect the peer to the --chain contracts-rococo-local

Tags: substrate-node, nodes, libp2p, peers, substrate-connect

I'm trying to have my node discover and connect to the blockchain terminal so that the peer count will update from 0 peers to 1 peers. However, I keep getting this message:

2024-03-15 18:38:36.394  WARN tokio-runtime-worker libp2p_identify::handler: [Relaychain] New inbound identify push stream from 12D3KooWRq75YzXpcop26cBjKFDwVAGfpZ3WtT6qKW5Bfir7NfvY while still upgrading previous one. Replacing previous with new.

This is my libp2p configuration:

const options = {

```
  peerId: peerId,
  addresses: {
      listen: ['/ip4/0.0.0.0/tcp/0/ws']
  },
  transports: [
    tcp(),
    webSockets(),
  ],
  connectionEncryption: [noise()],
  streamMuxers: [yamux(), mplex()],
  peerDiscovery: [
    mdns(),
    bootstrap({
      list: bootstrapNodes
    })
  ],
  services: {
    identify: identify(),
  },
  config: {
    peerDiscovery: {
      autoDial: true,
      mdns: {
        interval: 5000,
        enabled: true,
        broadcast: false,
      },
    },
  },
  connectionManager: {
    autoDial: true,
    maxConnections: 50,
    minConnections: 10,
  },
}

const node = await createLibp2p(options);
await node.start();
```

I've been stuck on this issue for a while, but I can't seem to figure out why its replacing the previous with the new. If anyone can help me with this issue, it'll be greatly appreciated.